# what is the best way to get live data from serial port and save it in SQL database?

Tags: asp.net, database, winforms, web-services, hardware

what is the best way to get live data from serial port and save it in SQL database? and display it on ASP.NET website ?

Is it something that can be done by webservices or client side programm is required to install on the machine ? any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3):

You'll need two separate applications.

One to read the data from the serial port and send it to your web application via web services to be written to the database.

The second would the be actual web application including the web services to receive and write the data to the database as well as displaying the data on the site once it is uploaded.

Comment: @super - How much C#/.NET do you know?

Comment: @super - It sounds like this could be a pretty complicated project, depending on how complex the data is and what you're going to do with it. I would suggest coming up to speed with WCF and figure out how to build your services. You'll also need to figure out how to properly read data from the serial port connection.